# Neo4j 2.0 Windows: Memory stops being allocated to service after a few service restarts

Tags: neo4j

This is odd behavior but I have been able to reproduce it 100%.  I'm currently testing Neo4j 2.0.1 Enterprise on my laptop and desktop machines.  Laptop has 8GB RAM i7 4600U and Desktop has 16GB RAM i7 4770k. (Both machines are running Windows 8.1 x64 ENT and the same version of Java (latest as of FEB 19, 2014).

On first boot of each, when I run an expensive (or not so expensive) query, I can see the memory allocation go up (as expected for the cache).  When starting the server, initial allocation is around 200-250mb, give or take.  After a few expensive queries, it goes up to about 2GB, which is fine, I want this memory allocation.  However, I have a batch script that stops the service, clears out the database and restarts the service (to start fresh when testing different development methods).

After 3 or 4 restarts, I noticed that the memory will NEVER climb above 400mb.  Processor usage sits around 30-40% during the expensive query, but memory never increases.  I will then get `Unknown Error` messages in the console when running other expensive queries.  This is the same query that after a full reboot of the system, would bring the memory usage up to 2GB.

I'm not sure what could be causing this, or if there is a way to make sure that memory usage continues to be allocated, even on service restart.  Rebooting a production server doesn't seem like a viable option, unless running in HA.

Comment: Are you sure the Neo4j process is really removed when using the stop script. My guess is that some dangling process still occupies resources that prevent the other and new process from allocating more.

Comment: Sir, on behalf of the community, I challenge you to share your logs!

Comment: I am 100% positive it's removed.  net stop Neo4j-Server stops the service and removes it from task manager.
What would my logs show?

Comment: video of the batch process killing the task: 
[YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72I8H8Vp480&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

Comment: Well, if you feel so secretive about the logs thing, just look at them yourself and tell us that they are fine, so we could proceed with the divination.

Comment: Dude, I'm not secretive.  Which logs would you like to see?  And for what reason?  This will help me pinpoint which logs to provide (As there are many).

Comment: Can you share your config and also data/log/console.log and data/graph.db/messages.log ? Thx

Comment: Log files are here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mdtse09v2hwr6s4/lRmOpuqEH9  I don't have a data/log/console.log file though... and I can't open the activity logs in a text viewer (they pop up as binary data)